# Show dialog from code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP.Net WebForms site, and my page has an html button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default mb-control" data-box="#message-box-default">Default</button>
```

Once clicked, this button will display the following div which is basically a modal dialog:

```
<!-- Message Boxes -->
            <!-- default -->
            <div class="message-box animated fadeIn" id="message-box-default">
                <div class="mb-container">
                    <div class="mb-middle">
                        <div class="mb-title"><span class="fa fa-globe"></span> Some <strong>Title</strong></div>
                        <div class="mb-content">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at tellus sed mauris mollis pellentesque nec a ligula. Quisque ultricies eleifend lacinia. Nunc luctus quam pretium massa semper tincidunt. Praesent vel mollis eros. Fusce erat arcu, feugiat ac dignissim ac, aliquam sed urna. Maecenas scelerisque molestie justo, ut tempor nunc.</p>                    
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right mb-control-close">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end default -->
```

This is working fine.  However, what I'd like to do is sometimes show this div from my Asp.net codebehind (C#).  So essentially what I need is a way to mimmick the button click from my codebehind.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm still new to .net so I appreciate your help!

Comment: you will need to use javascript to show something on the client without posting back.

Comment: Why not just put it in the load event handler when the server wants it to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show it on code behind since the server code only affect server side components. You can send a script to do it using [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

Comment: Thank you, I meant to respond earlier.  I didn't have experience with RegisterStartupScript and appreciate you pointing me in that direction